# Isolating specific methods used by app functions?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm attempting to get to grips with [Flex](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/01/14/flex/) (not Adobe Flex) in the hopes that it will make the transition to hardcore jailbreak development a little bit easier.

So, currently, I'm making a relatively simple patch for the Reminders app to always show all options for reminders and, as you can see here, I managed to do this by overriding the return value of `-(BOOL) shouldDisplayEditItem:(id) withVisibility:(int)` of the `EXReminderEditor` class:

[image]

However, I would also like to prevent the "Show Less..." button from appearing, as it's now non-functional, but I'm finding the responsible method difficult to isolate. I know that I'm likely looking for a method with a boolean return value but, even with using multiple search filters (such as `-(BOOL)`, `show`, etc), I just can't find the method for that button.

Considering this is the list of the executables and libraries, each containing mountains of classes and methods, simply looking through each one by one isn't really feasble:

- Executable

  - Reminders
- Libraries

  - AccountSettings
  - AddressBook
  - CoreFoundation
  - CoreGraphics
  - CoreLocation
  - CoreText
  - EventKit
  - EventKitUI
  - Foundation
  - GraphicsServices
  - libicucore.A.dylib
  - libobjc.A.dylib
  - libSystem.B.dylib
  - QuartzCore
  - SpringBoardServices
  - UIKit

My end goal is to be able to quickly isolate specific methods that apps use for certain things, so does anyone know of a relatively easy way to accomplish this?

I'm hoping for something akin to Chrome's developer tools, but I know that's very unlikely. So, failing that, could anyone advise me on likely naming scheme / location patterns that I can use?

Also, does anyone know what method that button uses? :D

Comment: I'm not sure what Flex development has to do w/ Jailbreaking an iOS Device.  In Flex you can make a button invisible by setting the visible property to false.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Forgot about Adobe Flex. This is what I'm referring to: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/01/14/flex/. I've removed the `flex` tag now.

Comment: I never heard of that before; but your question makes a lot more sense in that context.  Maybe there should be an tag for this.  Flex-Jailbreak-Utility or something similar.